# How to run R codes on remote machine from local machine

Tags: r, remote-server

maybe the question title is a little bit weird... I will explain more here...

Basically, suppose that I have a local laptop and a remote machine. I can of course run R tasks on the remote machine itself. Now I wonder if I can connect the remote machine from my local R and run the tasks on the remote machine while I still call these things in my local machine... that is I don't need to open R or type/source R codes on the remote machine.

One related thing is that I am considering to develop a small app with R-shiny. As far as I understand, though I just started looking into it, one can have R installed the local machine and use the app - the calculation will be done in R on the same machine. This question is essentially that if it is possible to add a feature of “connection to a calculation back end” in the app, i.e. by connecting to the remote machine, the task is done on the remote machine when one uses the app on his local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with RStudio Server. It runs RStudio inside a web server on the remote machine. You connect to it from the web browser on your local laptop, so you can still enter your R code on the local machine.

RStudio Server can be downloaded here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/